# Show menu after 10 px

Tags: jquery, scroll, hide, show

I need my 2 menus (top and side menu) to be hidden and first become visible once i start scrolling down... lets say after 10 px for instance. Anyone can help me achieve this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navigation_top">
    <ul>
        <li>Btn_1</li>
        <li>Btn_2</li>
        <li>Btn_3</li>
        <li>Btn_4</li>
        <li>Btn_5</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation_side">
       <ul>        
          <li><a href="#slice1" id="btn_1" class="anchorLink">slice1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#slice2" id="btn_2" class="anchorLink">slice2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#slice3" id="btn_3" class="anchorLink">slice3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#slice4" id="btn_4" class="anchorLink">slice4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#slice5" id="btn_5" class="anchorLink">slice5</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="slice1"></div>
    <div id="slice2"></div>
    <div id="slice3"></div>
    <div id="slice4"></div>
    <div id="slice5"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {height:100%; color:#FFF;}

.wrapper {width:100%; height:100%;}
.navigation_top {width:100%; height:50px; background-color:#000; opacity:.5; line-height:50px; position:fixed;}
.navigation_top ul {list-style:none;}
.navigation_top ul li {float:left; width:20%; display:block;}
.navigation_side {width:200px; height:auto; position:fixed; background-color:#FFF; margin-top:30%;}

#slice1 {width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#CCC;}
#slice2 {width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#999;}
#slice3 {width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#888;}
#slice4 {width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#777;}
#slice5 {width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#666;}
```

**Jquery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".anchorLink").click(function(event){        
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
});
```

here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/GA5NH/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide your menu first, then listen to the `scroll` event on `window` and check `scrollTop`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".anchorLink").click(function(event){        
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });

    $('.navigation_top').hide();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // the 10 below is the number of pixels down to show the menu
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) $('.navigation_top').show();
        else $('.navigation_top').hide();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you can listen to the `scroll` event on an element : http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

You can get the scroll position with `scrollTop` : http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ (or `scrollLeft` for a horizontal scroll)

An example :

```
$('#myElement').scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
       // Do some stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you implement it in my fiddle? im not so good with Jquery